# How to read two csv files and to concatenate them?

Tags: python, csv

First, I need to import two csv files.

Then I need to remove header in both files.

After that, I would like to take one column from both files and to concatenate them.

I have tried to open files, but I'm not sure how to concatenate.

Can anyone give advice how to proceed?

```py
import csv

x = []
chamber_temperature = []

with open(r"C:\Users\mm02058\Documents\test.txt", 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    with open(r"C:\Users\mm02058\Documents\test.txt", 'r') as file1:
        reader_1 = csv.reader(file1, delimiter='\t')

    for row in (reader):
        x.append(row[0])
        chamber_temperature.append(row[1])

for row in (reader_1):
    x.append(row[0])
    chamber_temperature.append(row[1])
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to import the same file twice.

Comment: yes, this is jst to see how it work. I want to append two same files...

Comment: but it doesn't work...Any idea?

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Any error traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mm02058\PycharmProjects\test\spajanje dva fajla.py", line 17, in <module>
    for row in (reader_1):
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate bug is that you are trying to read from `reader1` outside the `with` block, which means Python has already closed the file.

But the nesting of the `with` calls is just confusing and misleading anyway. Here is a generalization which should allow you to extend with more new files easily.

```py
import csv

x = []
chamber_temperature = []

for filename in (r"C:\Users\mm02058\Documents\test.txt",
                r"C:\Users\mm02058\Documents\test.txt"):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for idx, row in enumerate(csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')):
            if idx == 0:
                continue  # skip header line
            x.append(row[0])
            chamber_temperature.append(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of how you have structured your code, the context manager for file1 will close the file before it has been used by the for loop.

Use a single context manager to open both files e.g

```
with open('file1', 'r') as file1, open('file2', 'r') as file2:
    # Your code in here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in (reader_1):
x.append(row[0])
chamber_temperature.append(row[1])
```

You are getting this error because you have placed this codeblock outside the 2nd loop and now the file has been closed.

You can either open both the files at once with this

```
with open('file1', 'r') as file1, open('file2', 'r') as file2:
    # Your code in here
```

or you can use pandas for opening and concatenating csv files

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', header=None)
```

and then refer here [Concatenate dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)